Concourse: using load_var to import JSON file
Im trying to use load_var to import a JSON file into a Concourse build pipeline, I'm trying this:
 jobs:
  - name: loading-vars
    plan:
      - get: myjson
      - load_var: myjson
        file: myjson.json
        format: json
      - put: myjson

But I get the error

error: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot
unmarshal object into Go struct field GroupConfig.groups.jobs of type
string

Am I missing something?
